# Restrict certain user to access only from certain IP in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I need to restrict certain user from a BasicAuth configured system to come only from certain IP address but allow the rest to come from anywere.

I know that I can restrict access using `Deny` and  `Allow` directives and know also how to restrict access to users using `Require`. But I need a mix of both and I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Satisfy directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy). I believe it would look something like this:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/File
AuthName "Go away"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1
```

This will block everyone except 192.168.1.1 unless they enter a password.

If you only want to make the one IP enter the password and allow everyone else with no restrictions then it would be:

```
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Deny from 192.168.1.1
Allow from all
```